# Cleaning up shapefiles using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing

Is there a way to clean up shapefiles?

For example, some medians are filled in on a road shapefile I'm using.

How can I fix this kind of thing?

I'm using QGIS and working with a shapefile I downloaded from the county. In some placed the median is not filled in. I had been working with CAD in which case I can just modify the polylines.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the data that you're trying to work with? Provide screen shots, tools you're working with, etc.?

Comment: Do you want to clear the holes ?

Answer (score 2):

If those roads are polygons (not lines) and your question is "how do I fill in the holes?", I don't think there is a straightforward way in QGIS. But here is one way you can do it:

1. Create a large polygon in a separate layer that covers the entire extent of the map.
2. Use the difference tool to create a new layer with all the area not occupied by the road.
3. The new layer will have the "plugs" for the holes as well as some other junk. Delete the junk, and dissolve what's left with your original road layer.

Comment: There is a "Fill ring" tool in the advanced editing toolbar that can fill holes in polygons ... but I'm not sure if that's the point of the question ...